# MongoDB find by array of objects with different value

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a Mongo Collection like below :[image]

I am trying to write a query that returns the objects based on given **fromS** and **toS** in the array .

example of my array is :

```
[{
"from": "London",
"to":"New York"},
{
"from": "Manchester",
"to": "Paris"
}]
```

My expected result for giving above array to the query is to get object 5, and 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `$or` operator.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#specify-or-conditions

Something like this should work:

```
db.myCollection.find({
    $or: [
        {"from": "London", "to": "New York"},
        {"from": "Manchester", "to":"Paris" }
    ]
});
```